# Dynamically add or remove dimensions with D3js parallel sets

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to change the dimensions of my parallel sets chart dynamically, as previously asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534168/dynamically-new-dimensions-with-d3-js-parallel-sets).

I'm using the reusable chart created by Jason Davies:
http://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/

I create my chart using this code:

```
var chart = d3.parsets()
      .dimensions(["Survived", "Sex", "Age", "Class"]);

var vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
    .attr("width", chart.width())
    .attr("height", chart.height());

d3.csv("titanic.csv", function(error, csv) {
  vis.datum(csv).call(chart);
});
```

I have created a button that when clicked should call a function `change` that should change the dimensions to `["Survived", "Sex", "Class"]`.

The function:

```
function change() {
    vis.call(chart.dimensions(["Survived", "Sex", "Class"]));
}
```

When the function is called I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined` on line 90 which is within the `updateDimensions` function in the reusable chart.

Anyone has a solution for this or should I solve it by using the workaround by creating a new svg object with the new dimensions and remove the old one as `user1386906` mentions in a comment in the previously asked question?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to make the parallel set take different values which are in json for a data entity
I have did with some random number generator

```
 svg.datum(data)
      .call(chart
        .value(function(d, i) {
            var v1, v2, v3;
            v1 = d["Valu"];
            v2 = d["Val"];enter code here
            v3 = d["Value"];
            console.log(v1);
            console.log(v2);
            console.log(v3);
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            if (x < 5) {
                return v2;
            } else {
                return v3;
            }

        })
        .mapLevel(levelMap)
        .dimensions(arrayOfDimensions)
        //dimensions to be displayed by chart. (i.e "Cost Item", "Location" etc)
    );
```

There is three different values named, Value, val, valu , I want nodes to take different values for parallel nodes , So that each set of parallel node has different size of nodes 
example :

```
nodeP        node Parallel to nodeP
]             ]
]
```

has different size so ribbon connecting them has varying size from source node to destination node.